# Generic function and protocol Swift 4.2 +

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias, associated-types

I am having an issue creating a function that returns a generic type that conforms to the Codable protocol.

To give more context:

Below is a protocol with an associated type:

```
public protocol CodableProtocol {
        associatedtype T: Codable

        var httpMethod: HTTPMethods { get }
        func toDictionary() -> T
    }
```

Notice the toDictionary() method that returns a generic type that must conform to codable. For the most part it is easy to implement toDictionary() by defining the return as `Dictionary<String, String>`

However, the problem arises when the `Dictionary` has more than one data type. 
For example: `[String: [String: String/ Int], String: String]`
The value for the key in the dictionary is codable, so basically when implementing `toDictionary()` one needs to return a generic type that is constrained to Codable.

My problem is implementing the `toDictionary()` in the class returning a generic type and having that class conform to the protocol. I almost feel that defining a `type alias` in the class could fix it, but when I do it breaks conformance to the protocol.

Comment: It feels like this protocol is mis-designed. `T` doesn't promise to be a dictionary. It could be an Int. And it's not clear why a dictionary would be a good type here in any case (something as complex as this should be a struct almost aways). It's also not clear what the caller could do with the returned value or what extension could make sure of it. All that said, if you need to return "String or Int" that is solvable by using an enum that is either `.string(String)` or `.int(Int)`.

Comment: Before going down this rabbit hole, I would suggest taking a step back and showing what you expect the calling code to look like, and what a few concrete implementations look like. I believe there are much better designs here that won't have these issues.

Comment: Although maybe a struct would be best.. hmmm would be a whole lot easier..

Comment: I think I was just so focussed on a basic data structure that I couldn't see that a struct would fix this easily.. Thanks. If you answer put it into a struct I'll mark as answered. I'll let you know how the struct goes

Comment: Not a surprise but it works